# What is return type of `if` statement

Tags: scala

From Programming Scala book I read that in following code `configFilePath` constant will be type of `Unit`:

```
scala> val configFilePath = if (configFile.exists()) {
| configFile.getAbsolutePath()
| }
configFilePath: Unit = ()
```

But when I execute this code in REPL I get result of type `Any`. Why?

The book examples use Scala 2.8, and I use Scala 2.10.

Comment: It's not an `if` statement, it's an `if` expression. If it were a statement, it wouldn't have a return type, since statements don't return anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if (cond) { expr }` returns common base type of `Unit` and type of `expr`, just like `if (cond) { expr } else { () }`.

It is `AnyVal` for `Int`, `Char` and so on, `Unit` for `Unit` and `Any` for `AnyRef`:

```
scala> if ( false ) 1
res0: AnyVal = ()

scala> val r = if ( false ) { () }
r: Unit = ()

scala> if ( false ) ""
res1: Any = ()
```

Answer (score 1):

As always, an `if` statement evaluates a logical condition and has to return a logical result. Therefore: `scala.Boolean`. But the value is not in a `return` per say. The result of the evaluation is used in execution, but as you are doing it:

```
val configFilePath = if (configFile.exists()) {
    configFile.getAbsolutePath();// say this returns a String.
};
```

But what if that `configFile.exists()` returns `false`? Nothing will be placed into that variable, therefore the compiler will infer the type to `Any`, which makes sense since you provided no way to conclude the `type`.

Also, you are probably better off using `match`.

```
val configFilePath = configFile.exists match {
    case true => Some { configFile.getAbsolutePath }
    case false => None
};
```

The above is deterministic and should return an `Option[ReturnType]`, which is the default Scala way of handling such things.

Comment: yes, I understand it. But why in book written that return type will be `Unit` and when I execute this in REPL i get `Any`? You think is just typo in book? Or something changed since Scala 2.8 (Book use Scala 2.8, I use 2.10)?

Comment: Nice answer, I just wanted to add that the result of `configFile.getAbsolutePath()` needs to be wrapped in `Some()` for the return-type to be `Option[String]`. Otherwise the type-inference will take a common supertype of `String` and `Option` and again return `Any`.

Comment: @MyTitle: same result (`Any`) on `2.8.2.final`. Maybe it's about runtime type, not inferred type...

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement takes a statement/closure/variable. When using closures, the final statement is used to infer the type. Since `configFile.getAbsolutePath()` is a function evaluating to `String`.
`Unit` subclasses `Any` meaning either of the following works:

```
val configFilePath:Any = if (configFile.exists()) {configFile.getAbsolutePath()}
```

and

```
val configFilePath:Unit = if (configFile.exists()) {configFile.getAbsolutePath()}
```

**Edit**

The case may be that the condition is evaluating to false for instance

```
val map = Map(1 -> "1")
val result = if(map.get(2)=="1") "Whoopie!"
```

result here would be type `Any = ()` since there is no `else` and the value either doesn't
exist or the value is not equal to `1`
This would be more appropriate if you wish for the type to be `String`

```
val configFilePath = if (configFile.exists()) {configFile.getAbsolutePath()} else ""
```

Comment: `configFile.getAbsolutePath() is a function evaluating to Unit` - it's evaluated to `String`

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect other possibilities. `configFile.getAbsolutePath()` is a function unless I'm missing something.

Comment: It's a method, not a function.

Comment: Oh, and `if` is not a statement, it's an expression. If it were a statement, it wouldn't *have* a return value, that's the *definition* of "statement".