# Scala: if statement returning Any instead of Unit in a closure

Tags: scala, closures, return-type, scala-swing

I have the following code in a method:

```
aSides.foreach(as => as.side.terr match
{
  case r: TerrSRiver => paintSeq :+= ((g: Graphics2D) =>
    {
      g.setPaintColour(ColourInt.blue)
  g.fill(Polygon(as.paintStd(0.2)))
    }
  case _: TerrSCoast => paintSeq :+= ((g: Graphics2D) =>
    {
      g.setPaintColour(TerrSea.colour)
      g.fill(Polygon(as.paintStd(0.2)))
    }) //one case excluded for simplicity
```

paintSeq is declared outside the method

```
var paintSeq: Seq[Graphics2D => Unit] = Nil
```

This compiles and runs as expected. However if I add an if Statement to the first case:

```
case r: TerrSRiver => paintSeq :+= ((g: Graphics2D) =>
  {
    g.setPaintColour(ColourInt.blue)
    g.fill(Polygon(as.paintStd(0.2)))
    if (zoom > 50) g.setPaintColour(ColourInt.white)
  }
```

I get an error:

type mismatch;  found : Seq[swing.Graphics2D => Any]  required: Seq[swing.Graphics2D => Unit]  AreaESw.scala   /prStratSw/src/pGrid/pUISw  line 49 Scala Problem

The error refers to the paintSeq :+= method. **Why is the if statement returning Any rather than Unit?** I can get rid of the error by adding a line after the if statement:

```
val dummy = 0
```

However if I add in return Unit at the end:

```
case r: TerrSRiver => paintSeq :+= ((g: Graphics2D) =>
  {
    g.setPaintColour(ColourInt.blue)
    g.fill(Polygon(as.paintStd(0.2)))
    if (zoom > 50) g.setPaintColour(ColourInt.white)
    return Unit
  }
```

It Compiles with the following warning:

enclosing method setVisObjs has result type Unit: return value discarded

But when it runs I get the following error

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl$mcV$sp

Using "return ()" still gives the run time exception.

This is Scala Swing code, but I'm using Scala 2.10.3 in the JavaFx Eclipse download: 4.2.2 on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Type of if

The result type of `if (cond) expr` is the common base type of `expr` and `Unit`, just like `if (cond) { expr } else { () }`

See [What is return type of `if` statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436886/what-is-return-type-of-if-statement) for details.

### How to get Unit

To get an instance of type `Unit` you should use `()` literal:

```
if (zoom > 50) g.setPaintColour(ColourInt.white)
()
```

`Unit` value is the companion object of type `Unit`. It's not an instance of type `Unit`. Type of object `Unit` is `Unit.type`.

### Do not use `return` in lambda

The result of lambda is the result of the last statement in lambda body, so you could just add result value (in this case literal `()`) as the last line.

`return` in lambda will return from the surrounding method rather than from the lambda itself using exception (`NonLocalReturnControl`).

It's useful for java-style methods like this:

```
def firstNegative(seq: Seq[Int]): Option[Int] = {
  for {
    i <- seq
  } if (i < 0) return Some(i)

  return None
}
```

`if (i < 0) return Some(i)` here is lambda body. Equivalent code for this method:

```
def firstNegative(seq: Seq[Int]): Option[Int] = {
  seq.foreach{ i =>
    if (i < 0) return Some(i)
  }

  return None
}
```

Comment: "return ()" still gives the exception

Comment: @RichOliver: not `return ()`, just `()`. See `Do not use return in lambda` part.

Comment: Yes thanks that works, I have up-voted your answer. There's another question where it states "if" without "else" evaluates to Unit. That was causing my confusion

Answer (score 0):

You should have a else clause :

```
   if (zoom > 50) g.setPaintColour(ColourInt.white) else ...
```

Benoit