# Do if else statements in Scala always require an else?

Tags: scala

I have the following function which works fine:

```
def power(x: Double, n: Int) : Double = {
  if (n > 0 && n % 2 == 0) power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2)
  else if (n > 0 && n % 2 == 1) x * power(x, n-1)
  else if (n < 0) 1 / power(x, -n)
  else 1
}
```

If I change it to be:

```
def power(x: Double, n: Int) : Double = {
  if (n > 0 && n % 2 == 0) power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2)
  else if (n > 0 && n % 2 == 1) x * power(x, n-1)
  else if (n < 0) 1 / power(x, -n)
  else if (n==0 ) 1
}
```

I.e. change the final `else` statement to be an `else if`, then I get the following error trying to call the function:

```
> <console>:8: error: not found: value power
                power(2, 1)
                ^
```

I'm guessing this is because there is a possible return type of Unit because the value of `n` could meet none of the conditions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is return type of \`if\` statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436886/what-is-return-type-of-if-statement)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java "if-else" is a statement. In Scala it is an expression (think of Java's ternary `?:`), meaning that it always produces some value. As mentioned by som-snytt in comments, in case of a missing `else` block the compiler supplies `else ()`, which is of type `Unit`, which obviously conflicts with the expected type `Double` in your example.

Some valid examples of missing `else` are provided [in Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21508861/485115).

Answer (score 3):

No - In general, an `if` expression does not require an `else` clause.

Examples:

```
if (true) println("a")
// prints "a"

if (false) println("a") else if (true) println("b")
// prints "b"
```

As Nikita Volkov's answer says, though, it is necessary if you need the expression to have some type other than `Unit`.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct. The method must return a Double, yours would return Unit if non of the "if.." cases match. Actually, when you paste the second definition into the repl, you should get

> `<console>:11: error: type mismatch;`
>   
>   `found   : Unit`
>   
>   `required: Double`